# How to add picture to these JFrames?

Tags: java, image, swing

I want to add picture to every window that this code creates.

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class what {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random ran = new Random();
        while(true) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setName("" +ran.nextLong());
            frame.setBounds(ran.nextInt(700), ran.nextInt(890) + 10, ran.nextInt(700), ran.nextInt(700));
            JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
            frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame1.setVisible(true);
            frame1.setName("" + ran.nextLong());
            frame1.setBounds(ran.nextInt(700), ran.nextInt(890) + 10, ran.nextInt(700), ran.nextInt(700));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't call `setBounds()` on frames (or any other JComponent).  Let the window work out its own size, or call `setSize()`, not `setBounds()`.

Comment: [How to use labels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Do you intend to use the images as a background for other components added on top?

Answer (score 1):

```
JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("path_to_image.png"));
add(imgLabel)
```

Answer (score 1):

frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Image Path/Image.png")));